# Quartz Scheduler Testing scenario not working

Tags: java, linux, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm using `quartz scheduler` with my `spring` app. Everything works fine so far but while testing a scheduled job in future lets say a  month from now, I schedule a job, and then change the system time of my `linux` machine to that day and 5 mins before the trigger was supposed to fire. I waited, the trigger fire time came and went by but didn't fire. The other approach i was able to test was to change the fire time in the oracle table so that we don't need to change system time. It also works when i schedule a job for the next day at 4(without need to change any date, but I waited 24 hrs for that to fire and it did). I don't understand why accelerated system time does not work with quartz. Any explanation would be helpful. thanks!

P.S: I'm using the core libraries from quartz and not spring integrated quartz libs.

Comment: The Quartz scheduler probably picks up the System time when it starts up and maintains a clock/counter of it's own.  The fact that you change the System time then never gets picked up by Quartz because Quartz is using it's own clock/counter value.  The only way to actually verify it would be to swim thru the Quartz source code...

Comment: @lincolnadym thats gonna be hard to detect.when I change the system time, I restart my scheduler and the logs display the updated date-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some time spent on this, I enabled the logs for `org.quartz` and found that `quartz` was not initialized when the app loads. Following snippet will initialize `quartz` during startup:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>QuartzInitializer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>start-scheduler-on-load</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config-file</param-name>
            <param-value>quartz.properties</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```